# Change the Target Framework from .NET framework 4.7.2 to .NET core 2.2 for a ASP.NET Core app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an existing ASP.NET Core application whose target framework is .NET 4.7.2. I would like to change it to use .net core 2.2 instead.

How to do this?

Comment: In theory, if you are not using any full framework specific api, you can just change the target framework to `netcoreapp2.2` and change the app to use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` meta package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I am convinced there is no "one-click" solution and did it manually. Here is what I did

1. in VS 2019, create a brand new solution targeting .net core 2.2
2. created each project manually, added nuget packages targeted for dotnet core
3. copied source code files into each project
4. make sure the solution build and run